# Only SELECT yesterdays date with weird date format

Tags: mysql, date

I need to only SELECT data where the date field is yesterdays date. The only problem I'm having is that the data in the date field looks like the following 20160412 062815.000

I don't really care about the time, I just want to search dynamically for anything with yesterdays date. I've tried a multitude of CURDATE() -1 but I'm unsure how to just search the first 8 digits of the field.

Comment: The dataype is varchar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the date value is stored as a string, and the first 8 characters are always the date in `YYYYMMDD` format, then you can use a query like this:

```
select *
from your_table
where your_column like concat(date_format(current_date() - interval 1 day,'%Y%m%d'),'%')
```

One advantage of this query is that it can leverage an index on your date field, unlike the other answers so far.

Answer (score 0):

Format yesterday's date to a number and convert the date string also to a number.

```
select * from your_table
where date_format(curdate() - interval 1 day, '%Y%m%d') * 1 = date_col * 1
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/56527)

`*1` is a math operation that forces MySQL to convert strings to a number.

Comment: Thanks a lot, works like a dream. Thanks @scaisEdge and Ike Walker for your suggestions also.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `subdate(currentDate, 1)`

```
select * from your_table 
where subdate(currentDate, 1) =  DATE(your_date)
```